# Database is not getting updated after executing this program

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

Here is the code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Insertdb {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dsn1");
        PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("insert into Table1 values (?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1,1);
        ps.setString(2,"Sachin");
        ps.setInt(3,25000);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        {
            System.out.println(i +"records inserted");
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

The data base used is MS Access 2013.
The output of the above code on the console is: 1 records inserted

But when i open the database the record is not inserted. Is there any thing wrong in the code? If not what could be going wrong?

Comment: probably you need to commit transaction

Comment: how to commit transaction?

Comment: close all the connection, resultset and statement and then check.

Comment: thanks @xwhyz. Actually i disabled auto commit and used con.commit(). it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also add at the end.

```
finally{
    con.commit();
    ps.close();
    con.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Transaction from program to database must be committed to get reflected in JAVA.
Try doing con.commit();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use finally in your code if you are connecting with database or perform file operations.Because whatever happened on try block the finally block always executed.so you can use finally block for closing the database connection and close the file and commit or rollback the database records.